# Xcode 6.3.2 iOS 8.4.1 error message: "The Developer Disk Image could not be mounted"

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad

I have looked closely at the questions on this topic and the replies and have tried all the solutions suggested. I have followed this (excellent) video tutorial to the letter:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2O_8HAsz_gU

(ie I created my certificate, my AppID, and my Provisioning Profile).

But still I get this error message: "The Developer Disk image could not be mounted. (Your) iPad may be running a version of iOS that is not supported by this version of Xcode".

I am running OSX 10.10.5 on my MacbookAir, am running iOS 8.4.1 on the iPad that I have plugged into the MacbookAir (and on which I am trying to run the demo App) and am using Xcode 6.3.2.

If anyone has any suggestions, I would be so grateful.

Thanks!

Comment: Your iPad is running a version of iOS (8.4.1) that is not supported by your version of Xcode (6.3.2). Gosh, I think that's the same thing the error message told you. Anyway, update to Xcode 6.4.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved! I had to uninstall Xcode 6.3.2 first. Once I had done that, Version 6.4 became available for download on the App Store. My demo apps are now running successfully on my iPad.